# kex .. Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh

I've started getting a lot of error messages from ssh and scp.

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

But whatever I'm trying will always work after a couple of more
attempts.  **Can I do anything short of a shell loop to avoid having to
repeat my commands?**  I tried inserting

```
ConnectionAttempts 10
```

into `~/.ssh/config`, but to no avail.  I have no control over the
server.